# Best way to start activity when a Bluetooth device is in reach on Android

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth

I am writing an app on Android that needs to start an activity when a Bluetooth device is within reach and stop it again when the device is out of reach. It does not need to connect to the device just use it as an indicator on when to start and stop the activity. What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is going to be too resource intensive to be practical. Scanning for bluetooth devices is an expensive operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare receiver for [ACL_CONNECTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED) in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <receiver android:name=".YourBroadcastReciver">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Then in YourBroadcastReciver do what you need, but don't show new activity (it would be annoying for user) it would be better show/hide some [status notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).